# Avoid primary key constraint violation

Tags: c#, sqlite

When users enter some data in a dialog, i try to insert the data into an sqlite database table. However i have to check that there is no primary key constraint violation. I need some hint what's the best way to tell the user that this record exists already. Until now i think i have two choices:

1.) query for the record using 'select' along with 'where' and try to find out if that record exists already

2.) try/catch on the insert and check the errorcode 19 that tells about a constraint violation.

Sadly the number 19 must not really just be a primary key constraint violation but any constraint violation. I prefer  the first choice, but isn't it eating to much performance?

Why is there no exists functionality regarding to check the existance of a primary key and get the appropriate record data so i could inform the user with appropriate data, that this record exists already.

Thanks for any hints on this Topic.

Comment: Use select. Try-catch's purpose is to handle unexpected behaviour. This is a pretty typical case.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that does the check first then the insert if the record does not exist and returns a success or fail code.

Comment: Thanx for the hints!

Comment: This shouldn't come up. Users should never see or know about Primary Keys. They should know if they're adding something new or updating something existing. Your app should know that too.

Comment: Yes, i agree. Anyway a pk with three fields needs a wierd where clause having multiple AND statements. The syntax on definition of a compound pk is much easier.
From the users view, i'll prompt the user that this record existst already, the he/she can cancel the operation o press ok to edit the existing record.

Answer (score 2):

Use select - it would be even faster than try catch at application level.

Comment: I will use select. However i suggest to make it easier to use select on a primary key. In my case, the pk is a compound of three fields. For the select statement i'll have to use three AND statements. Could be easier to have the construct where primary_key=('val1',2,'val3'); This avoids three AND statements.